# Check if worksheet password protected without opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have been doing checks with worksbooks for things like if the sheet exists or what is in a cell without opening the workbook using this command

```
f = "'" & strFilePath1 & "[" & strFileType & "]" & strSheetName & "'!" & Range(strCell).Address(True, True, -4150)

CheckCell = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(f)
```

and it has been working well but now i am wanting to check if the sheet is Password protected without opening but haven't been successful. Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes!** It is possible. I discovered how to do it long time ago. I doubt this is mentioned anywhere in the web...

**Basic Introduction**: As you are aware, Microsoft Excel up until 2007 version used a proprietary binary file format called Excel Binary File Format (.XLS) as its primary format. Excel 2007 onwards uses **Office Open XML** as its primary file format, an XML-based format that followed after a previous XML-based format called "XML Spreadsheet" ("XMLSS"), first introduced in Excel 2002.

**Logic**: To understand how this works, do the following

1. Create a new Excel file
2. Ensure it has at least 3 sheets
3. Protect the 1st sheet with a `blank` password
4. Leave the 2nd sheet unprotected
5. Protect the 3rd sheet using `any` password
6. Save the file, say, as `Book1.xlsx` and close the file
7. Rename the file to, say, `Book1.Zip`
8. Extract the contents of the zip
9. Go to the folder `\xl\worksheets`
10. You will see that all the sheets from the workbook has been saved as `Sheet1.xml`,`Sheet2.xml` and `Sheet3.xml`

    [image]
11. Right click on the sheets and open it in notepad/notepad++
12. You will notice that all the sheets you protected has one word `<sheetProtection` as shown below

    [image]

So if we can somehow check if the relevant sheet has that word then we can ascertain whether the sheet is protected or not.

**Code:**

Here is a function which can help you in what you want to achieve

```
'~~> API to get the user temp path
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Change as applicable
    MsgBox IsSheetProtected("Sheet2", "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Function IsSheetProtected(sheetToCheck As Variant, FileTocheck As Variant) As Boolean
    '~~> Temp Zip file name
    Dim tmpFile As Variant
    tmpFile = TempPath & "DeleteMeLater.zip"

    '~~> Copy the excel file to temp directory and rename it to .zip
    FileCopy FileTocheck, tmpFile

    '~~> Create a temp directory
    Dim tmpFolder As Variant
    tmpFolder = TempPath & "DeleteMeLater"

    '~~> Folder inside temp directory which needs to be checked
    Dim SheetsFolder As String
    SheetsFolder = tmpFolder & "\xl\worksheets\"

    '~~> Create the temp folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If FSO.FolderExists(tmpFolder) = False Then
        MkDir tmpFolder
    End If

    '~~> Extract zip file in that temp folder
    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(tmpFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(tmpFile).items

    '~~> Loop through that folder to work with the relevant sheet (file)
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir(SheetsFolder & sheetToCheck & ".xml")

    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        '~~> Read the xml file in 1 go
        Open SheetsFolder & StrFile For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1

        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
            '~~> Check if the file has the text "<sheetProtection"
            If InStr(1, strData(i), "<sheetProtection", vbTextCompare) Then
                IsSheetProtected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    '~~> Delete temp file
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill tmpFile
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Delete temp folder.
    FSO.deletefolder tmpFolder
End Function

'~~> Get User temp directory
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

**Note**: This has been tested for `.xlsx` and `.xlsm` files.

Comment: thanks for your answer. A little more complicated than i would have liked but there appears to be no other way. Thanks a lot